# Why isn't my SQL query returning any records?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to get the number of records in one of my database tables where the `post_id` field is equal to the `$postID` variable I compare it to. When I swap `{$postID}` out with an integer such as `130`, the query returns results as expected. However, whenever I try to query my DB using the `$postID` variable, no results are returned. I've checked out what `$postID` contains to ensure that `post_id` is being compared to the right value, and it contains an integer value of `130`.

If the query works with a hardcoded `130` in place of `$postID`, why doesn't it work when I use `$postID` which is equal to `130` as well?

```
$postID = get_the_ID();
$postLikes = $wpdb->get_results('
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_post_likes WHERE post_id = {$postID}
');

echo "<pre>";
     var_dump($postLikes);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Variable substitution does not take place in single quoted strings.

Comment: This is correct. You're awesome, never knew that.

Comment: As addition the corresponding part in the php docs: [php: Single quoted](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) `[...]Note: Unlike the double-quoted and heredoc syntaxes, variables and escape sequences for special characters will not be expanded when they occur in single quoted strings.[...]`

Comment: you shouldn't really need a table for that, perhaps look at [add_post_meta()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta) there is also `update_ / get_ post_meta()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variable substitution does not take place in single quoted strings, see [Variable parsing](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing).

And I suggest you use a parameterized query instead of mixing the payload data into the actual statement, see [Protect Queries Against SQL Injection Attacks](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks)

```
$postLikes = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare( 
    'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_post_likes WHERE post_id = %s',
    get_the_ID()
));
```